Can't access the Django endpoints
Can't access the various Django endpoints. Tried accessing the endpoints such as http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/line-chart-data/
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/candlestick-data/
and etc, but got a 404.
urls.py
"""
URL configuration for mysite project.

The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to  For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.1/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Import the include() function: from django.urls import include, path
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""

# mysite/urls.py

from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from .views import line_chart_data, candlestick_data, bar_chart_data, pie_chart_data
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('charts.urls')),
    path('api/candlestick-data/', candlestick_data),
    path('api/line-chart-data/', line_chart_data),
    path('api/bar-chart-data/', bar_chart_data),
    path('api/pie-chart-data/', pie_chart_data),
]

views.py
# mysite/views.py
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view

@api_view(['GET'])
def candlestick_data(request):
    data = {
        "data": [
            {"x": "2023-01-01", "open": 30, "high": 40, "low": 25, "close": 35},
            {"x": "2023-01-02", "open": 35, "high": 45, "low": 30, "close": 40},
        ]
    }
    return Response(data)

@api_view(['GET'])
def line_chart_data(request):
    data = {
        "labels": ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr"],
        "data": [10, 20, 30, 40]
    }
    return Response(data)

@api_view(['GET'])
def bar_chart_data(request):
    data = {
        "labels": ["Product A", "Product B", "Product C"],
        "data": [100, 150, 200]
    }
    return Response(data)

@api_view(['GET'])
def pie_chart_data(request):
    data = {
        "labels": ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow"],
        "data": [300, 50, 100]
    }
    return Response(data)

settings.py
"""
Django settings for mysite project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 5.1.1.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.1/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.1/howto/deployment/checklist/


# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True
CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost', '127.0.0.1']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'corsheaders',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware'
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}

CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    'http://localhost:3000',  # Next.js frontend in development
    
]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny',
    ]
}




# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.1/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'


Inserted various enpoints to get a json format of the data but instead got a 404. The endpoints:

http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/line-chart-data/
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/candlestick-data/
etc.


comment this line "path('', include('charts.urls'))," or put it on the last position.

Still doesn't work.

Django does not need / at the end of a url path. Try removing them.
